# how to convert to money format in JS

Tags: javascript

i have a simple int like "77600" I want to convert it to "77 600" (basically i need to add a simple whitespace after thousands).

```
tmp_total = parseInt(tmp_total,10); //77600
tmp_total  = ...here goes some magic...;
$('#chekout_total #total').text(tmp_total);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tmp_total = parseInt(tmp_total,10); //77600
tmp_total  = tmp_total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1 ');
$('#chekout_total #total').text(tmp_total);
```

Hope this will help you! :)